# Tomcat "starts" but doesn't appear to be working

Tags: kubuntu, tomcat

So I am using:
Kubuntu 16.04 64bit, Apache Tomcat 7

Useful information (hopefully):
java -version

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

Variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
export CATALINA_HOME='/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.70'
```

ps -ef | grep tomcat

```
aaronh    4684  3977  0 13:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

sudo netstat -lnp | grep 4684

```
returns nothing
```

I've been starting Tomcat with (which doesn't throw an error):

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

When I check the browser, it just shows "this site can't be reached".

If I try and stop with:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
```

I just get:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

And that is all that is in the logs (only file in there is catalina.out)

Answer (score 0):

I removed JRE and JDK and installed default-jre and default-jdk.

Working now.